# Stereo mic passthrough with AVAudioEngine?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, core-audio, avaudioengine

I'm trying to create a graph with AVAudioEngine that takes input from the device microphone, and supports stereo output.

Right now the graph looks like this:

`[audioEngine.inputNode] --> [Mic input mixer node] --> [Summing mixer node] --> [audioEngine.mainMixerNode]`

As the output of `audioEngine.inputNode` is `1 ch,  48000 Hz, Float32`, I wanted to run through a mixer node after the mic so I can **a)** send the signal to multiple audio units and **b)** convert to a stereo signal for more interesting routing, panning etc…

However, the audio passthrough is only working if I set the **entire graph** to match the input format of `1 ch,  48000 Hz, Float32`, like this:

```
audioEngine.connect(microphoneNode!, to: microphoneInputMixer, format: inputSessionFormat!)
audioEngine.connect(microphoneInputMixer, to: summingMixer, format: inputSessionFormat!)
audioEngine.connect(summingMixer, to: mainMixerNode!, format: inputSessionFormat!)
```

I have two format variables, the mono `inputSessionFormat` and stereo `outputSettingFormat`, which is `2 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32, non-inter`.

As I understood from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiomixernode) AVAudioMixerNode should handle format conversion, but in this case it's refusing to play audio unless all connections are set to the same (mono) format. I've also tested this code with `AVAudioConnectionPoint` as well, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only AVAudioEngine's inputNode and outputNodes have the fixed formats. Use `nil` when connecting to/from these. Mixers will implicitly convert between their input and output formats. Connect to `microphoneInputMixer` using `nil`, and from `microphoneInputMixer` using the desired format. The `mainMixerNode` will take any input format and its output format cannot be set.

```
let desiredFormat = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 44100, channels: 2)
audioEngine.connect(microphoneNode!, to: microphoneInputMixer, format:nil)
audioEngine.connect(microphoneInputMixer, to: summingMixer, format: desiredFormat)
audioEngine.connect(summingMixer, to: mainMixerNode!, format: desiredFormat)
```